# Sorting alphabets & numerals

Tags: objective-c, sorting

i want to sort an array in such a way that numerals come after alphabets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want `-sortedArrayUsingFunction:context:` with a custom function which does your custom comparison.

See [this document](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/sortingFilteringArrays.html) for more information on sorting/filtering arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You will probably want to use the
[sortedArrayUsingSelector:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingSelector:) 
method.